# ARIMA Model - MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast few values using ARIMA Model. I get the following error. I have tried to remove the stationarity and other necessary conditions for the forecasting. Can someone point me out why this error is generated and how to fix this? Im new to Python. Thanks in advance.

Error completer error tree as follows.

```
MissingDataError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-35993c1e078a> in <module>
 37 from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
 38 print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
 ---> 39 dftest = adfuller(indexedDataset["like"], autolag='AIC')
 40 
 41 dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value', 
'#Lags Used','#Number of observations used'])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\stattools.py in adfuller(x, maxlag, regression, autolag, store, regresults)
239         if not regresults:
240             icbest, bestlag = _autolag(OLS, xdshort, fullRHS, startlag,
--> 241                                        maxlag, autolag)
242         else:
243             icbest, bestlag, alres = _autolag(OLS, xdshort, fullRHS, 
startlag,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\statsmodels\tsa\stattools.py in _autolag(mod, endog, exog, 
startlag, maxlag, method, modargs, fitargs, regresults)
 84     method = method.lower()
 85     for lag in range(startlag, startlag + maxlag + 1):
 ---> 86         mod_instance = mod(endog, exog[:, :lag], *modargs)
 87         results[lag] = mod_instance.fit()
 88 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
815                  **kwargs):
816         super(OLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
--> 817                                   hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
818         if "weights" in self._init_keys:
819             self._init_keys.remove("weights")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, weights, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
661             weights = weights.squeeze()
662         super(WLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
--> 663                                   weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
664         nobs = self.exog.shape[0]
665         weights = self.weights

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
177     """
178     def __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
--> 179         super(RegressionModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
180         self._data_attr.extend(['pinv_wexog', 'wendog', 'wexog', 
'weights'])
181 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
210 
211     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, **kwargs):
--> 212         super(LikelihoodModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
213         self.initialize()
214 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
 62         hasconst = kwargs.pop('hasconst', None)
 63         self.data = self._handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst,
 ---> 64                                       **kwargs)
 65         self.k_constant = self.data.k_constant
 66         self.exog = self.data.exog

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
 85 
 86     def _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs):
 ---> 87         data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
 88         # kwargs arrays could have changed, easier to just attach here
 89         for key in kwargs:

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
631     klass = handle_data_class_factory(endog, exog)
632     return klass(endog, exog=exog, missing=missing, hasconst=hasconst,
--> 633                  **kwargs)

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
 77 
 78         # this has side-effects, attaches k_constant and const_idx
 ---> 79         self._handle_constant(hasconst)
 80         self._check_integrity()
 81         self._cache = resettable_cache()

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in _handle_constant(self, hasconst)
131             ptp_ = self.exog.ptp(axis=0)
132             if not np.isfinite(ptp_).all():
--> 133                 raise MissingDataError('exog contains inf or nans')
134             const_idx = np.where(ptp_ == 0)[0].squeeze()
135             self.k_constant = const_idx.size

MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 6

dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
#Parse strings to datetime type
dataset['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'], 
infer_datetime_format=True)
indexedDataset = dataset.set_index(['Date'])

from datetime import datetime
indexedDataset.tail(5)

#plot graph
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Number of Likes")
plt.plot(indexedDataset)

#Determining the rolling statistics
rolmean = indexedDataset.rolling(window=12).mean()

rolstd = indexedDataset.rolling(window=12).std()
print(rolmean, rolstd)

#plot tolling statistics
orig = plt.plot(indexedDataset, color="blue", label="original")
mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color="red", label="Rolling Mean")
std = plt.plot(rolstd, color="black", label= "Rolling std")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.title=("Rolling Mean and Standard Deviation")

#Perform Dickey-Fuller test
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
dftest = adfuller(indexedDataset["like"], autolag='AIC')

dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value', '#Lags 
Used','#Number of observations used'])
for key, value in dftest[4].items():
dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)' %key] = value

print(dfoutput)

#Estimating trend
indexedDataset_logScale = np.log(indexedDataset)
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale)

movingAverage = indexedDataset_logScale.rolling(window=12).mean()
movingSTD = indexedDataset_logScale.rolling(window=12).std()
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale)
plt.plot(movingAverage, color="red")

datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage = indexedDataset_logScale - movingAverage
datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage.head(12)

#remove Nan Values
datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage.dropna(inplace=True)
datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage.head(10)

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
def test_stationarity(timeseries):

#determing rolling statistics
movingAverage = timeseries.rolling(window=12).mean()
movingSTD = timeseries.rolling(window=12).std()

#plot rolling statistics
orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color='blue',label='Original')
mean = plt.plot(movingAverage, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
std = plt.plot(movingSTD, color='black', label= 'Rolling std')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title=("Rolling Mean and Standard Deviation") 
plt.show(block=False)

#Perform Dickey-Fuller test:
print('Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:')
dftest = adfuller(indexedDataset["like"], autolag='AIC')
dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value', '#Lags 
Used','#Number of observations used'])
for key,value in dftest[4].items():
    dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
print(dfoutput)


test_stationarity(datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage)

exponentialDecayWeightAverage = 
indexedDataset_logScale.ewm(halflife=12,min_periods=0,adjust=True).mean()
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale)
plt.plot(exponentialDecayWeightAverage, color='red')

datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverageExponentialDecayAverage = 
indexedDataset_logScale - exponentialDecayWeightAverage
test_stationarity(datasetLogScaleMinusMovingAverageExponentialDecayAverage)

datasetLogDiffShifting = indexedDataset_logScale - 
indexedDataset_logScale.shift()
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)

datasetLogDiffShifting.dropna(inplace=True)
test_stationarity(datasetLogDiffShifting)

from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(indexedDataset_logScale)

trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid

plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale, label='Original')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(412)
plt.plot(trend, label='Trend')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(413)
plt.plot(seasonal,label="Seasonality")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(414)
plt.plot(residual, label='Residuals')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.tight_layout()

decomposedLogData = residual
decomposedLogData.dropna(inplace=True)
test_stationarity(decomposedLogData)

decomposedLogData = residual
decomposedLogData.dropna(inplace=True)
test_stationarity(decomposedLogData)

#ACF and PACF plates
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf

lag_acf = acf(datasetLogDiffShifting, nlags=20)
lag_pacf = pacf(datasetLogDiffShifting, nlags=20, method="ols")

#plot ACF
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(lag_acf)
plt.axhline(y=0,linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='-- 
',color='gray')
    plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='-- 
',color='gray')
# plt.title("Autocorrelation Function")

#Plot PACF
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(lag_pacf)
plt.axhline(y=0,linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
    plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
# plt.title("Partial Autocorrelation Function")
plt.tight_layout()

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

#AR MODEL
model = ARIMA(indexedDataset_logScale, order=(2, 1, 2))
result_AR = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
plt.plot(result_AR.fittedvalues, color='red')
print('RSS: %.4f'% sum((result_AR.fittedvalues- 
datasetLogDiffShifting["like"])**2))
print('Plotting AR model')

#MA MODEL
model = ARIMA(indexedDataset_logScale, order=(2,1,2))
results_MA = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
plt.plot(results_MA.fittedvalues, color='red')
print('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_MA.fittedvalues- 
datasetLogDiffShifting["like"])**2))
print('Plotting AR model')

 model = ARIMA(indexedDataset_logScale, order=(2,1,2))
 results_ARIMA = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
plt.plot(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues, color="red")
print('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_MA.fittedvalues- 
datasetLogDiffShifting["like"])**2))

predictions_ARIMA_diff = pd.Series(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues, copy=True)
print(predictions_ARIMA_diff.head())

#Convert to cumulative sum
predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum = predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum()
print(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum.head())

predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(indexedDataset_logScale["like"].iloc[0], 
index=indexedDataset_logScale.index)
predictions_ARIMA_log = 
predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum,fill_value=0)
predictions_ARIMA_log.head()

predictions_ARIMA = np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)
plt.plot(indexedDataset)
plt.plot(predictions_ARIMA)

indexedDataset_logScale

results_ARIMA.plot_predict(1,264)
# x=results_ARIMA.forecast(steps=120)
```

Comment: can you share the entire traceback / error

Comment: updated the question bro! its there now

Comment: what do you get from the following code: `indexedDataset.isnull().sum()`

Comment: ah! its just a line to see how many null values are there in the data file

Comment: what do you understand from the error

Comment: Im new to python. Basically what I get is that That some data might be missing

Comment: what is the output that you get when you print this `indexedDataset.isnull().sum()`

Comment: OMG! I cannot find the line `indexedDataset.isnull().sum()` in my code !!!

Comment: you need to add it after this line `indexedDataset = dataset.set_index(['Date'])`

Comment: I get the result as `like 10`
I added the following line to the code and now the error is gone! But a new one is there `indexedDataset = indexedDataset[indexedDataset != 0]`

The error now there is 
`MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans`

Comment: MissingDataError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-35993c1e078a> in <module>
     37 from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
     38 print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
---> 39 dftest = adfuller(indexedDataset["like"], autolag='AIC')
     40 
     41 dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value', '#Lags Used','#Number of observations used'])

Answer (score 1):

There are some missing values in your dataset, you need to preprocess your data before passing it to the seasonal_decompose method.

```
indexedDataset = dataset.set_index(['Date'])
indexedDataset = indexedDataset.fillna(method='ffill')
```

You can also check other methods to fill your missing values from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

Comment: Not working ! I added the following line to the code and now the error is gone! `indexedDataset = indexedDataset[indexedDataset != 0]`

Comment: But now there is a new error ! 
`MissingDataError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-35993c1e078a> in <module>
     37 from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
     38 print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
---> 39 dftest = adfuller(indexedDataset["like"], autolag='AIC')
     40 
     41 dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value', '#Lags Used','#Number of observations used'])
`

Comment: can you share the entire traceback

Comment: did you try my solution

Comment: what do you get when you print this `indexedDataset.isnull().sum()` after the line `indexedDataset = indexedDataset.fillna(method='ffill')`